# I cannot upsert in Mongoose for Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My schema is:

```
var VenueSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    ,rating : Number
})
```

And I am trying:

```
var v = new Venue()
v.name = venue.name
Venue.update({ id : Schema.Types.ObjectId(venue.id)}, v, {upsert: true})
```

But there is nothing in the DB. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `_id` instead of `id` and a plain JS object in the `update` call, and Mongoose will do the ObjectId casting for you.  Try this instead:

```
Venue.update({ _id : venue.id}, {name: venue.name}, {upsert: true});
```

Note that `name` doesn't appear in your schema, which probably isn't what you want.